# Can I 'propel somebody to do something'?

Tags: expressions, verbs

As the title states, I would like to convey the idea that a specific event urged some people to do something. The phrase as I would formulate it is:

**The advent of computers propelled scientists to seek new methods to solve the problem.**

Is this form correct?

Comment: _Propel_ is more commonly physical than a general term like _push_, which would work better. But why do you need a physical metaphor when you're describing a path? _The advent of computers led scientists to ..._

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the similar sounding _compel_, which means "to force or drive, especially to a course of action"

Comment: Yes, I guess I was just thinking of _compel_. However, isn't _compel_ closer to the meaning of _force_ or _coerce_ than to that of _push_ or _lead_?

Comment: I am compelled to reply to your comment to say that I don't think so. It could be a strong desire as well which pushes you to do something.

Comment: My own view is that a person can only be propelled when they are on wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I 'propel' somebody to do something'? Yes, but in context.

> As in:
>
> She propels me with her encouragement!

**propel**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/propel)

> to impel, drive, or cause to move forwards

*impel*

> 1. To urge to action through moral pressure; drive: I was impelled by events to take a stand.
> 2. To drive forward; propel.

So you can persuade, direct, etc but no compelling!

to compel:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/compel)

> 1. to cause (someone) by force (to be or do something)
> 2. to obtain by force; exact: to compel obedience.
> 3. to overpower or subdue